# Windows 10 with amd totally freezes on idle

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, freeze

My windows almost every hour totally freezes, but only if I don't do anything or just browsing. I have played for hours Assasin - no problem, trained model with 100% CPU utilization for the night- no problem.  So I believe this problem related with idle and power problem. Same problems may come with linux. Using Remote desktop (RDP) - might be trigger, but bug comes without even it/

Last chipset drivers installed, last video drivers, BIOS F23 - the last available version installed.

I tried to disable cool&quiet, global c-state control, power supply method - didnt help in BIOS settings.

Tried max performance and AMD balanced mode - same problem

My windows 10 1803 is only with up to june updates, is july updates is needed?

​

My PC:

```
AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor
Deepcool 530W Explorer DE530 PWM 120mm fan   - powersupply
Gigabyte GA-AB350M-DS3H V1.1 - motherboard
AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor
1070ti gtx
SSD
RAM: Samsung M378A2K43CB1-CTD 16GB (ram checked - no problem)
```

what can I do?

Comment: Rather than it being caused by idle states it is possible that it is caused by one of Windows' tasks which runs *during* idle time, like disk optimisation or similar... you've disabled all the power management features so it doesn't sound like they're at fault.

Comment: @Mokubai great suggestion, many people blames defruq, but it already turned of. Any ideas how get such tasks?

Comment: Type “Task Scheduler” into Windows Search or https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-open-task-scheduler-on-windows-10.html . It's a bit of a mess in there, with a lot of unrelated stuff, but you might find something that started running just before a system hang...

Comment: I was mainly thinking about defrag because it sounds suspiciously like hard drive failure, maybe a bad part of the disk or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had random freezes with my Ryzen CPU as well. 2700X and Vega 56 GPU. If you are experiencing issues with some Games with Launchers or Google Chrome not working also, then the problem is caused by Cryptsvc.dll. Took me a whole lot of time to figure it out after freezes didn't go away, even with a fresh Win10 install.

To find out if this is the issue, create a bat-file on your desktop with the following content:
SC Stop CryptSvc

save it as Crypt.bat and run it as administrator. If this fixes the crashes for a while (service will restart itself), you can go ahead and do the following:

Set the Cryptographic Services under Windows Services to run locally. Right click on preferences of the service, set it to run in local mode and save it. After this, go to registry (regedit in command prompt) and set the value "EnableLUA" in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" to "0".

That's it. Will mess a bit with your windows User Account Control, but it's the only possible fix, except you want to keep the batch-file solution as permanent solution.